# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: in anonymous inner class

Tags: java, inner-classes

Im' running this code on a Linux Red Hat with the sun/oracle JVM 1.6_23, inside a VMWare server.

After some times the JVM seem to be unable to access my anonymous inner classes.

My classpath is fine, since it works for a period.

All i got is errors like this one :

> `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`: `com/mycompany/impl/MyClassImpl$1`
>       at `com.mycompany.impl.MyClassImpl.markAsDeletable`(`MyClassImpl.java`:45).

line 45 is the first line below, it can't find my new Predicate

```
        DomaineVO domaineVO = Iterables.find(domainesVO, new Predicate<DomaineVO>() {

            @Override
            public boolean apply(DomaineVO input) {
                return input.getId().equals(domaine.getIdentifier().toString());
            }
        });
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Does the `MyClassImpl$1.class` file really exist in one of the folders on the classpath (or within some JARs)?

Comment: yes, the file is there. As i said, the code works for a time, then  stop to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, i think we might have put the finger on the problem.

We are running this code on jetty, and we use automatic deploy of the .war files.
By default jetty use the java.io.tmpdir to deploy the .war files.

Our problem was only on linux, and mostly early in the morning (as soon as the first office worker use the app).

The cause was the cleaning of the /tmp at night (made by a LOGROTATE command on our servers).

Rules of thumb : Never use /tmp for too long time, and make jetty deploy war in a directory of your own.

Thanks everyone

Comment: I encountered the same problem with the Eclipse Terminal plugin. I switched to the Linux Terminal and it was solved.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the JVM can't find the class file for the anonymous class. This would be named 'MyClassImpl$1.class' - if it's not present in the classpath, something must have deleted it. If it is present then there's something wrong with the JVM.

Comment: i guess there is something wrong with the JVM, but i wish i could learn what. (As i said, in another comment, the file is there.), I know i'm in a crazy situation.

Comment: @oneeyejack: another possibility if the file is there is that for some reason its access permissions are changed so that the JVM can't access it anymore.

Comment: Everything is inside a .war file, i think that if everything else is running, then this shouldn't be related to a permissions issue. Nick Fortescue talked about a possibility of a GC related issue. I'm trying to find the appropriate -XX options to get a better view of what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds very odd. Firstly if the code works for a time, as you say, the file must be there. Secondly, it is rare for a JVM to unload a class from memory once it has been used. Some JVMs will do it in tight memory situations or as part of a GC, but as an optimisation they normally stick around.

My only guess is you are using the JVM in a situation where ClassLoaders are changing. If you are using Netbeans (especially) but I think also eclipse, then if you partially recompile the code then classloaders might not match. Is this running within an IDE?

An alternative is a ClassLoader changing. If you re-release to a running webserver or application server, then an old class will not have a matching classloader for the new instance. The ClassLoader may not be able to find the old version, even though the file is there. Are you re-releasing to an Application/Webserver?

Finally, I guess this might be possible with Serialization. If the class is Serializable, and the serialVersionUIDs don't match I guess this might be able to happen. Are you doing any object serialisation here?

Comment: The problem is happening on a jetty server, and we don't use any kind of hot deployment features. The class is not Serializable. Is it possible that the JVM has a kind of issue similar to the PermGenSpace one?

Comment: Which method are you using to add your jars or directories to the jetty classpath? Are they being added as jars or directories? http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Classloading

Comment: All the code is contained inside .war files, we set the war path as this:
WebAppContext jettyWebAppContext = new WebAppContext();
  jettyWebAppContext.setWar(war);

  jettyWebAppContext.setContextPath(normalizedContext);
jettyServer.addHandler(jettyWebAppContext);

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can add any more insight. However, I'm sure it must be something to do with Jetty classloading. Maybe rephrase the question and repost giving exact details of how you use Jetty for releasing, and you might get a reply from a Jetty expert - I'm not one.

Comment: thank you very much for your insights, i'm now investigating on issues related to the GC, i hope the answer is there, i'll try to investigate the Jetty path also.