# some confused things about java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring

My war application has running in jetty container
it runs well at begin , some time later it will throw the **`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`** error just by same rest api interface .
And I'm *sure* the class is really exists at **classpath**.
i'm want to know why this happened and how to fix or avoid it !
thanks before
there has one of them stacks:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/uwaytech/modules/tdr/ctrl/TdrCtrl$1
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:982)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
        at com.uwaytech.request.RequestBodyFilter.doFilter(RequestBodyFilter.java:28)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
        at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:156)
        at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:201)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:178)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/uwaytech/modules/tdr/ctrl/TdrCtrl$1
        at com.uwaytech.modules.tdr.ctrl.TdrCtrl.cutStudentInfo(TdrCtrl.java:300)
        at com.uwaytech.modules.tdr.ctrl.TdrCtrl.getFuzzyList(TdrCtrl.java:262)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:854)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:765)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
        ... 46 more
```

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` is distinct from `ClassNotFoundException`. It usually means that the .class file is in the wrong directory for its package, or *vice versa*. You should certainly check whether you have a `com/uwaytech/modules/tdr/ctrl/TdrCtrl$1.class` file anywhere, and whether that is the correct directory for its package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the stacktrace the failure is happening for **com/uwaytech/modules/tdr/ctrl/TdrCtrl$1** which seems to be an anonymous class inside TdrCtrl. can you check the below link if it helps.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11035641/11207493

Comment: the problem is similar. it works at first and after a while then does not works and throw `NoClassDefFoundError`.And also deployed by jetty.but i have not idea why it happened,maybe the same reason caused.I have not idea to avoid it

Comment: you can try setting the tmp directory for jetty to a different folder and see it it happens again. something like **-Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/jetty/temp**

Comment: just now i clear the folder `/tmp`,and re-deploy application . and it works well . and then i will try change the tmpdir and watch it. thank you very much

Comment: Great. If works, please accept my answer and upvote. Thanks.